# MS SQL Server On-Premise Installation Keeps Saying ODBC Driver 17 installation is not found

Tags: windows-10, sql-server

Tried both downloaded .ISO and .EXE from the official Microsoft site, both failed on this ODBC 17 driver installation missing. With .ISO it prompted me to look for `msoledb.msi` file which is located a folder inside of the .ISO, selecting it still got the same complaint.

Based on this [post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/384784/how-to-solve-problem-microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for.html), SSMS must be v18.3+. Mine is v18.12.

My local OS is Windows 10 (64 Pro).

Comment: The ODBC 17 driver installation is for the client. If the server is on site, that is fine. But for the client to work an ODBC driver needs to be installed on the client system.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I don't recall selecting `client connectivity` or alike.

Comment: This is probably a mismatch between 32-bit and 64-bit softwares. To check for your driver, open *Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)* for both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions, in the Drivers tab, and check in which one is found this driver.